# Reordering with two separate Java concurrent structures

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm starting a long-running process on a queue of items, and while an item is either scheduled to be processed or is being processed, I want to disallow some other operation. My code basically looks like this:

```
public class LongRunningProcess extends Thread {
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Item> pending = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private final Set<Item> active = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Item, Boolean>());

    public LongRunningProcess() {
        // add items to pending; no more items will ever be added
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (! pending.isEmpty()) {
            // The peek/add/remove pattern here is important. The number
            // of items that are active or scheduled is always decreasing.
            // Because isScheduled checks pending before checking active,
            // this order of operations ensures that we never miss an item
            // as it is being switched from one collection to the other.
            Item nextItem = pending.peek();
            active.add(nextItem);    // <---Can any of these get reordered?
            pending.remove();        // <---+
            processItem(nextItem);   // <---+
            active.remove(nextItem); // <---+
        }
    }

    public boolean isScheduled(Item item) {
        return pending.contains(item) || active.contains(item);
    }
}
```

Will this work the way I expect, or is it possible for the highlighted code block above to be reordered? Can you please point me to any relevant specs?

## Edit:

@Banthar's helpful comment led me to the [java.util.concurrent package documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility), which answers my question definitively:

> The methods of all classes in `java.util.concurrent` and its subpackages extend these guarantees to higher-level synchronization. In particular:
>
> - Actions in a thread prior to placing an object into any concurrent collection *happen-before* actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the collection in another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will this work the way I expect, or is it possible for either of the two highlighted items above to be reordered? Can you please point me to any relevant specs?

The short answer is that because both collections are concurrent classes, there is no way that the `active.add(...)` will happen after the `pending.remove()`.

- The `pending.peek();` and `pending.remove();` accesses the `volatile` field `head`.

  ```
  private transient volatile Node<E> head = new Node<E>(null);
  ```
- The `active.add(nextItem);` accesses internal locking `volatile` fields:

  ```
  compareAndSetState(0, acquires)) {
  ```

Because both of your collections are concurrent classes, they both have internal locks or `volatile` variables so the methods calls have read/write memory barriers which ensure a "happens before" guarantee.  This ensures that the operations cannot be reordered because of the [Java Memory Model](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#reordering).

However, that doesn't mean that your logic is correct or that there aren't race conditions when you look at how the other threads are consuming those two collections.  In addition, those calls are not atomic so you could have 3 threads that do:

1. t1 -- Item nextItem = pending.peek();
2. t2 -- Item nextItem = pending.peek();
3. t1 -- active.add(nextItem);
4. t3 -- removes nextItem from active and processes it or something
5. t2 -- active.add(nextItem);
6. t3 -- removes nextItem from active and processes it **again**

Comment: That was what I thought, thanks. No other threads are accessing these collections; this is a single-threaded task (there is no `t2` or `t3`). Do you have any references handy that I could look at?

Comment: @BrandonMintern http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770166/is-concurrenthashmap-get-guaranteed-to-see-a-previous-concurrenthashmap-put

Comment: Here's JMM information @BrandonMintern.  http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#reordering

Comment: Thank you both! Banthar's link led me to [the java.util.concurrent documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility), which answers this question definitively.

Comment: Yeah.  That javadoc is quoting the JMM @BrandonMintern.