# Why java concurrentmap gives slight difference in calculating doubles using multithread

Tags: java, concurrency

I am doing matrix multiplication by trying using multi-threads approach, but the calculation between doubles are not always the same for the same matrix.
there are the codes:

for the matrix:

```
private  ConcurrentMap<Position, Double> matrix = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public Matrix_2() {}


  public double get(int row, int column) {
    Position p = new Position(row, column);
    return matrix.getOrDefault(p, 0.0);
  }
  public void set(int row, int column, double num) {
    Position p = new Position(row, column);
    if(matrix.containsKey(p)){
      double a = matrix.get(p);
      a += num;
      matrix.put(p, a);
    }else {
      matrix.put(p, num);
    }
  }
```

for multiplication

```
    public static Matrix multiply(Matrix a, Matrix b) {
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    Matrix c = new Matrix_2();
    IntStream.range(0, a.getNumRows()).forEach(r ->
      IntStream.range(0, a.getNumColumns()).forEach(t ->
          IntStream.range(0, b.getNumColumns())
              .forEach(
                  v -> 
           threads.add(new Thread(() -> c.set(r, v, b.get(t, v) * a.get(r, t)))))
      ));
    threads.forEach(Thread::start);
    threads.forEach(r -> {
        try {
          r.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          System.out.println("bad");
        }
      }
    );
    return c;
  }
```

where *get* method get the double at specific row and column, *get(row, column)*, and the *set* method add the given number to the double at that row and column.
This code works fine at the integer level but when it comes to double with a lot precision, it will have different answers for the multiplication of same two matrices, sometimes can be as large as 0.5 to 1.5 for a number. Why is that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is ConcurrentHashMap.get() guaranteed to see a previous ConcurrentHashMap.put() by different thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770166/is-concurrenthashmap-get-guaranteed-to-see-a-previous-concurrenthashmap-put)

Comment: Using a ConcurrentMap is a really inefficient way of representing a Matrix unless it is very sparse.  Note: your implementation isn't thread safe which is mostly the reason you get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A concurrent collection can help you write thread-safe code, but it does not make your code *automatically* thread-safe.  And your code -- principally your `set()` method -- is ***not*** thread safe.

In fact, your `set()` method does not even make sense, at least not under that name.  If the implementation is indeed what you intend, then it seems to be more of an `increment()` method.

My first suggestion would be to simplify your approach by eliminating the middle `IntStream`, or at least moving it into the threads.  The objective here would be to avoid any two threads ever manipulating the same element of the map.  You could then also use a *bona fide* `set()` method in conjunction, as there would be no contention for individual matrix elements.  The `ConcurrentMap` would still be helpful in that case.  Most likely that would run faster, too.

If you must keep the structure of the computation the same, however, then you need a better `set()` method, one that accounts for the possibility that another thread updates an element between your `get()` and `put()`.  If you don't account for that then updates can be lost.  Something along these lines would be an improvement:

```
public void increment(int row, int column, double num) {
    Position p = new Position(row, column);
    Double current = matrix.putIfAbsent(p, num);

    if (current != null) {
        // there was already a value at the designated position
        double newval = current + num;

        while (!matrix.replace(p, current, newval)) {
            // Failed to replace -- indicates that the value at the designated
            // position is no longer the one we most recently read
            current = matrix.get(p);
            newval = current + num;
        }
    } // else successfully set the first value for this position
}
```

That approach will work with any version of Java that provides `ConcurrentMap`, but of course, other parts of your code already rely on Java 8.  The solution offered by @Sumitsu leverages API features that were new in Java 8; it is more elegant than the above, but less illustrative.

Note also that it would not be surprising to see see *small* differences in your result in any case, because reordering floating-point operations can cause different rounding.

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't fully analyzed your code for `multiply`, and John Bollinger makes a good point (in the comments) regarding the rounding-error inherent to floating-point primitives, your `set` method would seem to have a possible race condition.

Namely, while your use of [`java.util.ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) guarantees thread safety *within* `Map` API calls, it does nothing to ensure that the mappings could not have changed *in between* invocations, such as between the time that you invoke [`containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) and the time that you invoke [`put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-), or between the time that you invoke [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) and the time that you invoke [`put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-).

As of Java 8 (which your use of lambdas and streams indicates you are using), one option to rectify this problem is to make the check-existing + get + set sequence atomic via the [`compute` API call](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-). [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) allows you to provide a key and a lambda (or method reference) specifying how to mutate the value mapped to that key, and [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) guarantees that the lambda, which encompasses your full check-and-set logic, will be executed atomically. Using that approach, your code would look something like:

```
public void set(int row, int column, double num) {
    Position p = new Position(row, column);
    matrix.compute(p, (Position positionKey, Double doubleValue)->{
        if (doubleValue == null) {
            return num;
        } else {
            return num + doubleValue;
        }
    });
}
```